# Exception NoClassDefFoundError: ReflectionManager with Hibernate 6

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, gradle

I tried to implement Hibernate 6 in my Kotlin Project, but i get the following error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager`

This is my build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.8.10")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javacord/javacord
    implementation("org.javacord:javacord:3.8.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")
    // https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.3.1.Final
    implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.3.1.Final")
//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc
//    implementation("org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.43.0.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0")
//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects
//    implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects:6.3.1.Final")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2
    implementation("com.h2database:h2:2.2.224")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(8)
}
```

And this my code:

```
fun main() {
    val registry = StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build()
    val sessionFactory = MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory()
    val session = sessionFactory.openSession()
    session.beginTransaction()
    session.persist(Account(829707526215172136L, 639095276619169813L, 1337))
    session.transaction.commit()
}
```

I already tried to implement the hibernate-commons-annotations, because this was someone else's solution, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you'd need to import `hibernate-common-annotations` library to make it work, now it's missing in your gradle build file:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations